# Given a password: LENNO9, How many ways can we construct a new one using exactly the same letters and numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Would this be a permutation problem? Since I'm currently trying to do it but I only know n = 6 but what is my r?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a permutation problem, but with repeated elements.

In this case, the permutations where only the repeated elements interchange are the same permutation. And for each element repeated $t$ times, the are $t!$ such permutations, so your usual number of permutations for $n = 6$ elements must be divided for $t!$ for each element repeated $t$ times to give the actual number of different passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Given $n$ objects there are $n!$ ways to permute them. However, in the case that some of the objects are identical, we must divide $n!$ by the ways in which we can permute the repeated elements. Precisely speaking, if we have a collection of $n$ objects among which there are groups of of $r_1,r_2,...r_k$ repeated objects then the number of distinct permutations is $$\frac{n!}{\prod ^{k}_{i=1} r_i!}$$
Example: The number of distinct permutations of the letters in the word "banana" is $$\frac{6!}{3!2!}=60.$$